# How can I use array using "row index" in python?

Tags: python, arrays, row

I made code in python

There's so many arrays, what I want to do is 
extract value of arrays and add it to array_matrix in row 
and make a label too 
and every circle `row = row + 1`

This is some part of my code, 
I know the form of 
`array_matrix[row,0:3] = array1(u) and label_matrix(row,:) =[1 0]`
isn't correct.

Please let me know what to change.

```
row = 0
array_matrix = []

for n in range(0,64,8):  
  array1.append(dct_temp[0,1])
  array2.append(dct_temp[1,0])
  array3.append(dct_temp[0,2])
  array4.append(dct_temp[1,1])

  u = (index-1,index+1,1)  # index = index of max value of array
  array_matrix[row,0:3] = array1(u)
  array_matrix[row,4:7] = array2(u)
  array_matrix[row,8:11] = array3(u)
  array_matrix[row,12:15] = array4(u)

  label_matrix(row,:) =[0 1]

  row = row + 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to know what all your variables are initialized to. I do not understand what you mean when you say "what I want to do is extract value of arrays and add it to array_matrix in row and make a label too and every circle row = row + 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dict

```
dict = {"labelA",arrayVal}
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [123, 234, 456]
d = {'a': [], 'b': []}
d['a'].append(list1)
d['a'].append(list2)
print d['a']
```

For your array you can use a notation like

```
array[FROM INDEX ROW:TOINDEX ROW, :]
```

The : means take all cols 
FROM INDEX ROW:TOINDEX ROW means take all values from the FROM INDEX upto the TOINDEX.